# different marshaling behavior on different computers

Tags: java, dom, jaxb, marshalling

I encountered a strange behavior in marshaleng with JAXB marshaller. 
Unfortunately, I can not bring the code of these models (from production) because I do not have the right to upload it to the network. And to come up with test models with this behavior did not work. I will try to describe the problem in words.

I have complex model generated by JAXB from XSD. I receive this model(JAXB object) in my SOAP web service and get part of this request.

```
org.w3c.dom.Element partOfRequest = fullRequest.getAny();
```

After that I try convert `partOfRequest` to `String` and save to database.

```
@Override
public String unMarshalElementToString(Element element) {
    try {
        Document document = element.getOwnerDocument();
        DOMImplementationLS domImplLS = (DOMImplementationLS) document.getImplementation();
        LSSerializer serializer = domImplLS.createLSSerializer();
        return serializer.writeToString(element);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**And In this point I have problems:**

When I start App on my machine - I have correct string with namespaces.
When I start App on first test machine - I have correct string with namespaces.
But when I start App on second test machine - I have string with differing namespaces. And weird is added `xmlns=""`.

How is this possible? The same 123.jar file runs on different computers, with the same java version, but do you get different results when marshalling? which way to look? check what? how can this be?

Comment: Check that the Java versions *that are **actually** used* to run the code are the same.  Check that the application classpaths are the same.  Check that the versions of dependent libraries are the same.  Check that someone hasn't tweaked the JVM on one or other platform; e.g. via the [Java Endorsed Standards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/standards/) mechanism or similar.

Comment: @Stephen C I create new questions after this, where I can write simple examle and write more details about problem. look it please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188560/jaxb-marshal-to-string-works-differently-on-different-computers