# JAXB marshal to string works differently on different computers

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have this test java app:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Car {

    @XmlElement(namespace="http://www.example.com/CAR_NAME")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(namespace="http://www.example.com/CAR_PRICE")
    private int price;

    @XmlElement(namespace="http://www.example.com/CAR_BUS")
    private Bus bus;

    //constructors, getters and setters

 @XmlRootElement
 public class Bus {

    @XmlElement(namespace="http://www.example.com/BUS_NAME")
    private String name;

    @XmlElement(namespace="http://www.example.com/BUS_PRICE")
    private int price;

    //constructors, getters and setters

@XmlRootElement
public class Request {

    @XmlAnyElement
    private Element element;

    //constructors, getters and setters
```

And I try convert string xml to `Element`  set this `element` to `Request`  and convert request to `string`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {

        String hz = "<car xmlns:ns6=\"http://www.example.com/CAR_BUS\" xmlns:ns5=\"http://www.example.com/CAR_NAME\" xmlns:ns2=\"http://www.example.com/CAR_PRICE\" xmlns:ns4=\"http://www.example.com/BUS_PRICE\" xmlns:ns3=\"http://www.example.com/BUS_NAME\">\n" +
                "    <ns5:name>CarName1</ns5:name>\n" +
                "    <ns2:price>999</ns2:price>\n" +
                "    <ns6:bus>\n" +
                "        <ns3:name>BusName1</ns3:name>\n" +
                "        <ns4:price>666</ns4:price>\n" +
                "    </ns6:bus>\n" +
                "</car>";


        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Car.class, Bus.class, Request.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Element documentElement = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(hz))).getDocumentElement();


        Document document = documentElement.getOwnerDocument();
        DOMImplementationLS domImplLS = (DOMImplementationLS) document.getImplementation();
        LSSerializer serializer = domImplLS.createLSSerializer();
        String s = serializer.writeToString(documentElement);

        System.out.println(s);

        System.out.println("------------------------------");

        Request request = new Request(documentElement);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(request, sw);
        String s1 = sw.toString();
        System.out.println(s1);

    }
}
```

When I start this application on my machine I get next  output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<car xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/CAR_PRICE" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/BUS_NAME" xmlns:ns4="http://www.example.com/BUS_PRICE" xmlns:ns5="http://www.example.com/CAR_NAME" xmlns:ns6="http://www.example.com/CAR_BUS">
    <ns5:name>CarName1</ns5:name>
    <ns2:price>999</ns2:price>
    <ns6:bus>
        <ns3:name>BusName1</ns3:name>
        <ns4:price>666</ns4:price>
    </ns6:bus>
</car>
------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<request xmlns:ns6="http://www.example.com/CAR_BUS" xmlns:ns5="http://www.example.com/CAR_NAME" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/CAR_PRICE" xmlns:ns4="http://www.example.com/BUS_PRICE" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/BUS_NAME">
    <car>

        <ns5:name>CarName1</ns5:name>

        <ns2:price>999</ns2:price>

        <ns6:bus>

            <ns3:name>BusName1</ns3:name>

            <ns4:price>666</ns4:price>
    </ns6:bus>
</car>
</request>
```

But When I start this application on test computer I habe next output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<car xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/CAR_PRICE" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.
com/BUS_NAME" xmlns:ns4="http://www.example.com/BUS_PRICE" xmlns:ns5="http://www.example.com/CAR_NAME" xmlns:ns6="http://www.example.com/CAR_BUS">
    <ns5:name>CarName1</ns5:name>
    <ns2:price>999</ns2:price>
    <ns6:bus>
        <ns3:name>BusName1</ns3:name>
        <ns4:price>666</ns4:price>
    </ns6:bus>
</car>
------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<request xmlns:ns6="http://www.example.com/CAR_BUS" xmlns:ns5="http://www.example.com/CAR_NAME" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.com/CAR_PRICE" xmlns:ns4="http://www.example.com/BUS_PRICE" xmlns:ns3="http://www.example.com/BUS_NAME">
    <car>

        <name>CarName1</name>

        <price>999</price>

        <bus>

            <name>BusName1</name>

            <price>666</price>
    </bus>
</car>
</request>
```

On the test machine missing tags `ns5, ns6, ns2`

I do not understand how this can be. The same version of Java, the same application but different output. Because of this, I have problems in the production server. How to fix it or where to find the cause?

Comment: Same advice as before!  Check that the Java versions that are actually used to run the code are the same. Check that the application classpaths are the same. Check that the versions of dependent libraries are the same. Check that someone hasn't tweaked the JVM on one or other platform; e.g. via the Java Endorsed Standards mechanism or similar.

Comment: @Stephen C thanks for the answer. I checked 1000 times java version. and they are the same. Versions of libraries, I do not know how they can be different, because I run the same jav file with libraries inside. Classpaths ... in both cases I run from the root of drive C.  `Check that someone hasn't tweaked the JVM on one or other platform` - here I don't know how to do it.

Comment: 1) How did you check the version?  2)  So you are saying that your application a single self-contained JAR file with no external dependencies?  3)  Read the link in my comment on the previous question.

Comment: There is a line break in the middle of an attribute in one of your XML samples.  Is it really there of is that a copy-paste error?

Comment: @Stephen C I found the reason. On the server where it does not work there is a library `xmlsec-1.5.0`. but now I don’t know how to run my application, since this library is being used by another application

Comment: Where is the library installed?  In the JRE / JDK installation itself?

Comment: In both folders))) Now we install java to another folder and try start with another java

Comment: That is one way to solve it ....

Comment: yes it worked. spent two days in search)))) thanks for help and advice!